# Pytorch summary only works for one specific input size for U-Net

Tags: python-3.x, multidimensional-array, deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I am trying to implement the [UNet architecture](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1505.04597.pdf) in Pytorch. When I print the model using `print(model)` I get the correct architecture:

[image]

but when I try to print the summary using (or any other input size for that matter):

```
from torchsummary import summary
summary(model, input_size=(13, 572, 572))
```

I get an error:

```
RuntimeError: invalid argument 0: Sizes of tensors must match except in dimension 1. Got 70 and 71 in dimension 2 at /Users/distiller/project/conda/conda-bld/pytorch_1579022061893/work/aten/src/TH/generic/THTensor.cpp:612
```

[image: error message]

However, it works perfectly if I give the input_size as `input_size=(3, 224, 224))`( like it worked for this person [here](https://github.com/usuyama/pytorch-unet)). I am so baffled.

Can someone help me what's wrong?

**Edit**: I have used the model architecture from [here](https://github.com/jaxony/unet-pytorch/blob/master/model.py).

Comment: Please provide the definition of you u-net module. It sounds like you've done a custom implementation of u-net? Nobody can tell you anything definitive if you don't provide your model definition.

Comment: @jodag Thank you. I am editing the answer to provide the link from where I used the model definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This `UNet` architecture you provided doesn't support that shape (unless the depth parameter is <= 3). Ultimately the reason for this is that the size of a downsampling operation isn't invertible since multiple input shapes map to the same output shape. For example consider

```
>> torch.nn.functional.max_pool2d(torch.zeros(1, 1, 10, 10), 2).shape
torch.Size([1, 1, 5, 5])
>> torch.nn.functional.max_pool2d(torch.zeros(1, 1, 11, 11), 2).shape
torch.Size([1, 1, 5, 5])
```

So the question is, given only the output shape is 5x5, what was the shape of the input? Was it 10x10 or 11x11? This same phenomenon applies to downsampling via strided convolutions.

The problem is that the `UNet` class tries to combine features from the downsampling half to the network to the features in the upsampling half. If it "guesses wrong" about the original shape during upsampling then you will receive a dimension mismatch error.

To avoid this issue you'll need to ensure that the height and width of your input data are multiples of `2**(depth-1)`. So, for the default `depth=5` you need the input image height and width to be a multiple of 16 (e.g. 560 or 576). Alternatively, since 572 is divisible by 4 then you could also set `depth=3` to make it work.

Comment: Thank you. That was very helpful. As I got this response, I also landed up some explanation here: https://github.com/jvanvugt/pytorch-unet which is basically the same you said. Yours is more detailed though. Thank you for that.